# Why would a replicated database have less strain?

Tags: database, replication, database-performance, database-replication

If it's possible to have a high-level conversation about database replication, that's what I'm looking for.

Imagine I have a replicated read-only database, created with the intent to use it for reporting.  The benefit is that users aren't hammering the primary db for reporting data, those queries are offloaded to the secondary database.  But if I set up realtime delivery, now that secondary db is getting read requests as well as update statements from the primary.  Won't your replicated db be failure prone, to the same point as if you used one db for both transactional and reporting functions?

To put it another way, what is the performance benefit of any of the realtime replication methods (I'm only familiar with log shipping) over common CRUD operations that a read-write, transactional database would run into?

Comment: What is this question about? If you create a copy of your production database just for reporting then your main database when you run DML's runs faster. And all operations work better. You divide the load into many databases. So what is the problem?

Comment: @AdamLeszczyński The question is about the load put on the reporting database by the replication effort: is it 1:1 with the original transactions?

Obviously, if I ship logs periodically, the strain on the database will be mitigated to those update cycles.  But if I'm continuously shipping my transaction, is that going to put the same load on the Reporting Server that would be placed on the Primary Server, from the initial transactions/queries?

Comment: Without replication you have: On the primary server you have: SELECT statements and DML statements, reporting statements. If you create a replication, then: On primary you have: SELECT statements and DML statements. On the replicate you have DML statements and reporting statements. You don not have the load that is generated from SELECT statements on the source. And more advanced replication systems also do not replicate DML statements that have been rolled back (only committed).

Comment: @AdamLeszczyński Thank you.  That's what I was looking for.  If you want to post that as an answer, I'd be happy to select it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AWithout replication you have:

1. On the primary server you have:

   - SELECT statements,
   - DML statements,
   - reporting statements.

If you create a replication, then:

1. On primary you have:

   - SELECT statements,
   - DML statements.
2. On the replicate you have:

   - DML statements,
   - reporting statements.

You don not have the load that is generated from SELECT statements on the source. All log-based replication systems do not replicate the SELECT statements to the Replicate System. They do not change the data, and there is no trace of them in the database log.

More advanced replication systems also do not replicate DML statements that have been rolled back (finished with ROLLBACK statement). Only committed statements are replicated (finished with COMMIT statement).